# Dumping a windows hibernation in ubuntu

Tags: windows, hibernate

For future reference and saving me a bunch of time, I would like to know how to dump a windows hibernation on its physical partition, so I can mount it's volume as rw without having to reboot my rig, starting the resume, dumping it, and rebooting back to linux.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the Windows  hibernation file i.e. `hiberfil.sys` so that you can mount the  windows  hibernated partition 
type this command in terminal:

`sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda1 /media/windows`

(Replace `/dev/sda1` with your windows partition and create `windows` directory inside /media using `sudo mkdir /media/windows`  if it is not present).

Note: It can cause problem in Windows resume.